# Need to name websites on localhost running on different Ports

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I have my development PC on Windows 7 for ASP.NET and running Visual Studio 2010 and IIS 7 (NOT using the development web server). I have created multiple websites on different ports on my PC. E.g. http://localhost:8080 points to Website A. But when I open the site in Visual Studio, the project name shows as http://localhost:8080, as follows.

[image]

I would like to change that name to http://WebsiteA or http://WebsiteA:8080. Some identification.

I edited hosts and added 
127.0.0.1   WebsiteA

Ping works fine. Also browsing WebsiteA:8080 works fine. But when I try opening the site (http://websitea:8080) in Visual Studio, it says Web site does not have Frontpage server extensions installed.

Is there any way to at least rename what's shown in the project list in Visual studio. I just need an identification on each website. I have about a dozen project and more may be added.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a way. This is what I did. Went to IIS Management, Created a new Website - Give it a name WebsiteA, Choose the folder where the web is located and give it a Host Name - WebsiteA. Click OK

Then go to Application Pools. You'll see your Host name there. Change the ASP.Net version to 4.0 or whatever you want. Then add a hosts entry 127.0.0.1 WebsiteA.

Now you can add http://WebsiteA in Visual Studio.

Thanks for all the help guys

Answer (score 1):

IIS in Windows 7 allows you to have [named virtual hosts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28WS.10%29.aspx). You can use that to separate out your sites. Visual studio cooperates with the naming of the virtual hosts. You will need to configure your visual studio project to operate against IIS (for debugging and running) rather than the visual studio built in web server.

Comment: Trying that now. I'm not using the development server. Using IIS

Comment: Then named virtual hosts are the way to go :) If you are checking in your project file (you configure the IIS instance in the project, not the solution), make sure that you uncheck "Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)" so that everyone can configure their own IIS instance locally.

Comment: Sorry, lambacck didn't understand. Right now I have no other developers. I'm running VS on a single development server. I just need some identification for each project in VS. Have attached a screen shot above. Thanks for your help